# Excel, Split name with more than one words of first name or last name or middle name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I separate the `last name` `middle initial` and `first name`

I have a name with two or more given name or last name or middle name for example

```
Mendoza, John Lloyd Dela Cruz
Torres, Michael Pineda
```

How can i split that if I have different count of words per column? and get only the first letter for `middle name`? Is this possible? If not can you suggest me a solution. I have many data

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show desured result for each sample value.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & share some sample data with us,  help us to fix the issue!

Comment: I gave two example of name ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that that

- **Last Name** is the first substring ending with a comma
- **First Name** is the first word after the comma
- **Middle Initial** is the first letter of the second word after the comma.

If that is not the case, you will need to clarify your question.  *Do so by editing your original question*

If that is really the case you can use the following formulas:

```
Last Name:       =LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)
Middle Initial:  =MID(A2,1+FIND(" ",A2,1+FIND(" ",A2,1+FIND(",",A2))),1)
First Name:      =MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,FIND(" ",A2,1+FIND(" ",A2,1+FIND(",",A2)))-2-FIND(",",A2))
```

Algorithm for first name and middle initial:

- For `Middle Initial`, return the first letter of the 2nd word that follows the comma.
- For `First Name`, return the 1st word following the comma.

[image]